# C# - Generate "identity" like Id's with NoSQL (MongoDB)?

Tags: c#, mongodb, unique, identity, mongodb-.net-driver

I've been using MongoDB with C#, and have been using ObjectIds, then later GUIDs for my Entity Ids.  I hate looking at these Id's, I think it's counter intuitive... I'd really like to be able to use integers or longs, like relational DBs Identity column. But I'm having a hard time finding a way to do it.  If I use collection max + 1, that will lead to race conditions.  I've read about using a Hi-Lo Generator algorithm, but how does that work? What if I have 10 app servers running the same code? Does that mean I have to have 10 hi lo identity ranges per collection?

If someone can point me to a C# algorithm to share that would be great!  I've seen RNGCryptoServiceProvider by the way, but that's not guaranteed to be unique, and it's not a sequential int/long Identity.  I'd rather use Hi-Lo at that point...

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write your own id generator and use it. [Here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-WriteacustomIdgenerator) you can find how. But `ObjectId`  was designed to be unique across all shards/replica sets. So each shard can generate unique id independently from others. With int id in distributed database you will have many problems.

Comment: I've created an implementation of this here: https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/MongDBIntIdGenerator - it's a work in progress, and needs more tests etc... but it's a start

Answer (score 1):

Guids may not be pretty to look at, but they are tested and tried.

You can go out of your way to try and prevent clashes on integer sequences but in the end, I think you'll find it's not worth the trouble. This is especially true for distributed environments that tend to change over time.

Comment: I have the answer set to the below response since he had a link to a generator, but both of you are correct... I should just go back to Guid or ObjectId, and stop thinking of pretty relational integer Id's.

Answer (score -1):

---

This is way to go: github.com/alexjamesbrown/MongDBIntIdGenerator

Comment: This won't work in the case of concurrent inserts or if docs are ever deleted.