# How to make an integer Id generator?

Tags: c#, mongodb

As it known, mongoDb default driver doesn't support automatic integer Id generation.
I spent 2 days for thinking how to implement my own id generator of unique integer values.
So, how to make it ?

Comment: If is not mandatory to be integer you might want to use a **GUID** as a quick solution...

Comment: @cad: even better quick solution would be sequential ints: 0, 1, 2, ...

Comment: is there a specific reason for not using object IDs as mentioned in `http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs` Did you have a look at this discussion on customId generator `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855084/c-sharp-generate-identity-like-ids-with-nosql-mongodb`

Comment: @vlad : Not sure if is better. The point of sequential is learning which is the next number... and usually this is not thread safe  (maybe with a singleton you can make it safe)

GUID in other hand might have some problems.
If you have time check this cool article in codinghorror: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html

Comment: @cad: If the thread safety is a concern, one can protect the generator with a `lock`. If GUIDs are thread-safe, they are doing the same.

Comment: @Vlad, I don't know why, but default IdGenerator's is done without using of lock or anything else. Check this - https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/Bson/Serialization/IdGenerators/IdGenerators.cs

Comment: @Tim: the lock must be somewhere inside `BsonObjectId.GenerateNewId()`

Comment: @Tim: and for ints, you can use [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx), which is basically faster.

Comment: @Vlad: GUIDs (and MongoDB ObjectIDs) are thread safe for reasons that have nothing to do with locks. They use various strategies for distributed uniqueness without locking. System.Guid doesn't use locks either.

Comment: @Sean: can you somehow back your claim that `System.Guid` doesn't use locks? In .NET 4 `Guid.NewGuid()` calls into ole32.dll's `CoCreateGuid`, and I cannot trace into that function.

Comment: @Vlad: Sure. GUIDs are "globally unique" (across all computers, everywhere), so locks wouldn't be sufficient anyway. Read Eric Lippert's "GUID Guide" for more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/04/24/guid-guide-part-one.aspx, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/04/30/guid-guide-part-two.aspx, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/05/07/guid-guide-part-three.aspx

Comment: @Sean: I've read already all the 3 articles. Although uniqueness between the computers in ensured by using (e.g.) MAC address, the uniqueness inside the same system still needs locking (or "interlocked operation") in some form, needn't it? If not, could you please find an exact citation from the articles you provided?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12602/discussion-between-sean-reilly-and-vlad)

Answer (score 7):

Its not good practice to make auto increment Id in MongoDB, as I will hurt in scaling your server, but If you want to make auto increment value it is not advisable to iterate your collection, Instead make a separate table (sequence like concept) and read value from there and increment it using findAndModify. It will be unique per table.

```
> db.counters.insert({_id: "userId", c: 0});

> var o = db.counters.findAndModify(
...        {query: {_id: "userId"}, update: {$inc: {c: 1}}});
{ "_id" : "userId", "c" : 0 }
> db.mycollection.insert({_id:o.c, stuff:"abc"});

> o = db.counters.findAndModify(
...        {query: {_id: "userId"}, update: {$inc: {c: 1}}});
{ "_id" : "userId", "c" : 1 }
> db.mycollection.insert({_id:o.c, stuff:"another one"});
```

Comment: but I don't understand why using another collection for storing current max Id doesn't hurt a scaling of a server

Comment: Is also hurts only it is faster than iterating whole collection

Comment: More importantly, this method is atomic. Iterating over the whole collection is not.

Comment: It will hurt scaling because it will now require TWO server calls to insert a record (one to get the generated ID, and the other to insert the record).    But not by much in a typical transactional system.   If you have streaming inserts, as with maybe a logging or instrumentation system, this additional overhead may cap IO, though.

Answer (score 3):

**I would use a GUID as primary key instead of an integer.**
It has mainly two benefits

- It is thread safe
- You don't need to worry about calculating next ID.
- Code needed to get new ID is pretty easy

  Guid.NewGuid()

Check this useful [article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/) in CodingHorror that explains pros and cons of using GUID over classical integer IDs.

Comment: Main reason to use int Id is that we building the system which works with external services, which uses int Id's. And there is some replication of our entities in mongodb to MSSQL. And there is no option to use GUID ID's in MSSQL

Comment: MSSQL certainly does support Guids.  They are called uniqueidentifier.

Comment: A big reason to not use GUID is that GUIDs are usually uniformly distributed, and that will cause horrible index fragmentation using b-trees. If you must use a GUID, be sure to use a GUID that has a sequential generation algorithm. ObjectID is sequentially generated. If you can't use ObjectID directly, consider using the string form of ObjectID. This will at least not cause index fragmentation.

Comment: Using a sequentials GUID == using IDs :) Same problems but 16bits instead of 4.


I thought that having uniformly distributed data was beneficial to a b-tree as they were in equilibrium... but it was a long time since I pass that subject in uni and maybe I am confusing AVL,B,B+ and B* :):)

Comment: @cad: Using a sequential GUID != using an autoincremented ID, as sequential "type 1" GUIDs still have a distributed generation algorithm, and don't require locks. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/04/30/guid-guide-part-two.aspx for more details.

Comment: @Sean: Thanks for link. I am going to read it while my build is running :)

Comment: @cad: Also, uniformly distributed data is the worst thing you can put into a b-tree, because you need to resize every on-disk block. With on-disk data structures, fragmentation is the enemy. Sequential IDs (of all kinds) are better, because the B-tree needs to only be inserted to at the end, and buckets never need to be split: they can be written to until they are full, and then an entirely new bucket can be created and added to the end of the tree.

Comment: GUIDs take more disk room (by increasing record size), and more compute time to search, compare and sort (there are 16 bytes, rather than 4 for an Int32).   Also, sequential IDs are easier for humans to see, query, and comprehend:  a suprising amount of work gets done by eyeballing data in a query tool, or Excel, or something similar.  Most people can instantly spot a difference in a 5- or 6-digit number, but GUIDs take some sweat to process.

Comment: We use GUIDs as PKs in a few tables at work and they drive me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

A late answer, but I thought I'd post this:

https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/MongDBIntIdGenerator

I made a start on an incremental ID generator.
Note - this is far from ideal, and not what mongodb was intended for.

Answer (score -4):

Something like that:

```
public class UniqueIntGenerator : IIdGenerator
{
    private static UniqueIntGenerator _instance;

    public static UniqueIntGenerator Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    static UniqueIntGenerator()
    {
        _instance = new UniqueIntGenerator();
    }

    public object GenerateId(object container, object document)
    {
        var cont = container as MongoCollection;
        if (cont == null)
            return 0;

        var type = cont.Settings.DefaultDocumentType;
        var cursor = cont.FindAllAs(type);
        cursor.SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("_id"));
        cursor.Limit = 1;

        foreach (var obj in cursor)
            return GetId(obj) + 1;

        return 1;
    }

    private int GetId(object obj)
    {
        var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
        var idProperty = properties.Single(y => y.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BsonIdAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault() != null);
        var idValue = (int)idProperty.GetValue(obj, null);
        return idValue;
    }

    public bool IsEmpty(object id)
    {
        return default(int) == (int)id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with MongoDb, but: Why all the time getting arguments as `object`s and casting them around?

Comment: Even if it was thread-safe it wouldn't work with multiple web-servers.

Comment: @Vlad, because that IdGenerator is general for many collections. So method GenerateId accept parameters of type object. And there is no way I found to get the Id property of found item

Comment: There are massive concurrency problems with this approach. Two documents being inserted at nearly the same time can very easily have the same id, which can cause crashes and data corruption.